# How can I force a wsus client to download updates?

Tags: wsus

How can I force a wsus client to download all updates after I have approved them in the wsus console?

`wuauclt.exe /detectnow` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

That's the command to use, but it won't force a download, it just makes the client check in with WSUS and ensure it's interfacing with it.

The downloads happen based on the clients' Windows Update settings.

If the detection worked and the computer is communicating with WSUS, then (in Windows 7+ anyway) Windows Update will say something like "You receive updates:  Managed by your system administrator" (if you didn't lock it down totally via GPO, you will also have the option "Check online for updates from Microsoft Update").

[image]

If this is the case, then all is working, and you just need to hit "Check for Updates" on the client.

Comment: ATM I try this on SBS 2011, I approved a lot of updates and in the sbs console under computers > server > updates > update status there are 51 Missing updates, however when I click check for updates it doesn't download them, it just shows me 1 important update is available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can force a Windows client to download and install updates when you want.
ABC-Update is a freeware tool available from http://abc-deploy.com/abc-update, and it is designed to do just what you are asking.

Example, To download and install updates from a WSUS server

---

```
C:\>ABC-Update.exe /S:WSUS /A:Install /C:SecurityUpdates /Q:IsInstalled=0
```

Windows Update Version: 7.5.7601.17514
Update API Version: 6.0

```
Action     : Install
Server Type: WSUS
Query      : Type='Software' AND IsInstalled=0
Category   : SecurityUpdates
Title      : *
```

Connecting to WSUS

---

```
Missing    Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553371) 32-Bit Edition
Missing    Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2826023) 32-Bit Edition
Missing    Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2892074)
```

Build collection of updates to download:

---

```
Adding: Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553371) 32-Bit Edition
Adding: Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2826023) 32-Bit Edition
Adding: Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2892074)
```

Downloading updates...

---

```
Download Result: Succeeded
Successful downloads:
1> Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553371) 32-Bit Edition
2> Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2826023) 32-Bit Edition
3> Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2892074)
```

Updates will be installed now

---

```
Start  : Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553371) 32-Bit Edition
Status : Succeeded
Start  : Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2826023) 32-Bit Edition
Status : Succeeded
Start  : Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2892074)
Status : Succeeded
At least one update require a reboot.
```

C:>

If you encounter problems, then checling the Windows Update Agent log is your fiirst step.
By default, the Windows Update client records all transaction information to the following log file:

```
%windir%\Windowsupdate.log
```

More info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902093